# Como enderezo una Imagen en python

Tags: python, imagen, opencv

He estado buscando la manera de enderezar una imagen escaneada , mas exacto un formulario ,necesito una función que automáticamente lo enderece, he intentando con

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('D:/Consecu.jpg',0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
                       cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]

if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle

(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)

rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h),
                         flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC,
                         borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
cv2.putText(rotated, "Angle: {:.2f} degrees".format(angle),
            (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

print("[INFO] angle: {:.3f}".format(angle))
cv2.imshow("Input", image)
cv2.imshow("Rotated", rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me rota la imagen no encuentra un grado (0,0) de inclinación , como podría rotar el marco o detectando lineas , que me las organice horizontalmente

necesito una función que la enderece automáticamente y me lo deje así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Nicolás. Puedes explicar mejor qué sucede? Explica lo que has intentado y que errores o problemas concretos tienes ,para poder ayudarte sobre eso. Recuerda leer [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: El código que muestras parece extraido de [esta página](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/) aunque es solo un pequeño fragmento. ¿Has intentado el resto de técnicas explicadas en esa página? ¿Dónde te has quedado atascado? De todas formas, como solución "precocinada", tienes también el módulo [Alyn](https://github.com/kakul/Alyn)

Comment: Si correcto Estuve mirando el código de esa pagina, pero no encuentra un angulo de desviación , me encuentro atascado ya que todas las funciones que he encontrado no me sirven

Answer (score 15, accepted):

El problema es que el algoritmo que estás aplicando, sacado de https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/ está específicamente diseñado para texto como el que se muestra en esa misma página:

[image: Ejemplo]

En las imágenes usadas en ese artículo, resulta que todos los píxeles de "tinta" están dentro de un rectángulo y ese rectángulo es precisamente el que se busca con el código:

```py
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
```

Básicamente lo que hace ese código es detectar cuál es el rectángulo que dejaría fuera sólo los píxeles que no son tinta. El rectángulo que encontraría sería el que te marco aquí en rojo:

[image: Rectangulo hallado]

Una vez hallado el rectángulo es fácil encontrar su ángulo y usarlo para enderezar el texto.

Por desgracia este truco no sirve en tu caso, ya que los píxeles de "tinta" aparecen dispersos por toda la página, y en concreto hay muchos pixeles negros cerca de las esquinas de la imagen. Como consecuencia, el rectángulo mínimo que engloba la tinta para tu caso, es un rectángulo igual a la página entera. Por eso sale el ángulo cero.

En cambio tu caso tiene una característica muy interesante, y es que al tratarse de un formulario impreso, contiene gran cantidad de líneas horizontales (la rejilla del formulario).

Usando la transformada de Hough podemos encontrar todas esas rectas. Esta transformada te da para cada recta el ángulo que forma con la horizontal. De hecho encontraría muchas rectas en tu imagen, la mayoría horizontales, pero también algunas verticales. Esto sería por ejemplo lo que podría encontrar si nos limitamos sólo a líneas con más de 1000 píxeles:

[image: Lineas encontradas por la transformada de Hough]

(Las líneas no se han dibujado completas, sólo un trozo para no tapar por completo a las originales).

Vemos que en algunas zonas (las barras negras anchas) detecta un amasijo de líneas con ángulos variables. Eso podríamos haberlo mejorado si antes de pasarle la imagen hacemos una detección de bordes (ej: canny). Pero no importa mucho en este caso porque el resto de las líneas finas las ha encontrado perfectamente.

Lo que podemos hacer es revisar todas las líneas que ha encontrado y quedarnos con los ángulos que más frecuentemente aparecen, que corresponderá a los de las líneas horizontales de la rejilla. Para este cometido nos viene muy bien la clase `Counter` del módulo estándar python `collections`.

El siguiente código hace todo lo antes descrito (he optado por volcar el resultado a otro fichero, en lugar de mostrarlo por pantalla, pues lo estoy ejecutando en un servidor sin terminal gráfica):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Leer la imagen
imagen = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
# Convertirla a gris e invertirla (negativo)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

# Aplicarle un threshold para dejarla binaria
# (los pixels serán 0 ó 255)
binaria = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
                cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]


# Usar la transformada de Hough para encontrar líneas
# en la imagen binarizada, con una resolución de medio
# grado (pi/720) y quedándose sólo con las líneas que
# alcancen puntuación de 1000 o más (que serán las
# más largas)
lineas = cv2.HoughLines(binaria, 1, np.pi/720, 1000)

# Recopilemos qué ángulos ha encontrado la transformada
# de hough para cada una de las líneas halladas
angulos = []
for linea in lineas:
    theta = linea[0][1]
    angulos.append(theta)

# Ahora contemos cuántas veces aparece cada ángulo
from collections import Counter
veces = Counter(angulos)

# Y quedémonos con el ángulo que más veces se repite
angulo = veces.most_common()[0][0]

# Cambiar el sentido de la rotación si el ángulo es mayor de 180º
if angulo > np.pi/2:
   angulo = -angulo
print("[INFO] angulo: {:.5f}".format(angulo))

# Ahora enderecemos la imagen, girando (en negativo) el ángulo detectado
(h, w) = imagen.shape[:2]
centro = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(centro, -angulo, 1.0)
girada = cv2.warpAffine(imagen, M, (w, h),
            flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

# Y volcamos a disco el resultado
cv2.imwrite("corregida.jpg", girada)
```

Esto es lo que sale en el fichero `"corregida.jpg"` (he reducido a la mitad su resolución para pegarla aquí, pues Stack Overflow se quejaba del tamaño):

[image: Resultado]

## Actualización

Como el usuario reportó algunos casos de imágenes en las que no se giraba correctamente, estuve revisando el algoritmo. He hecho las siguientes mejoras:

1. En lugar de binarizar la imagen mediante un *threshold* he aplicado un filtro Canny. Esto también convierte la imagen a fondo negro y líneas blancas, pero las líneas son los bordes (cambios de blanco a negro) en la imagen original. Esto evita que las zonas donde hay franjas de tinta anchas Hough encuentre muchas líneas solapadas.
2. En lugar de quedarme con el ángulo más veces repetido, me quedo con los tres más veces repetidos y calculo su promedio.
3. Transformo el ángulo antes de aplicarlo a la imagen, restándole π/2 y *lo más importante* pasándolo a grados antes de calcular la matriz de transformación. Esto es crucial. Era un *bug* tal como lo hacía antes (que le pasaba radianes) y es milagroso que pese a todo y por casualidad girara la cantidad correcta.

Con estas mejoras lo he aplicado a unas cuantas imágenes, giradas en diferentes sentidos o sin girar, y en todas ellas sale lo correcto.

Este es el nuevo código (lo he refactorizado a una función):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


def estan_cercanos(a1, a2, error):
    cases = np.unwrap([a2-error, a1, a2 + error])
    return cases[0] <= cases[1] <= cases[2]

def enderezar(entrada, salida):
    # Leer la imagen
    imagen = cv2.imread(entrada)

    # Convertirla a gris y detectar bordes
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    binaria = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

    # Usar la transformada de Hough para encontrar líneas
    # en la imagen binarizada, con una resolución de medio
    # grado (pi/720) y quedándose sólo con las líneas que
    # alcancen puntuación de 1000 o más (que serán las
    # más largas)
    lineas = cv2.HoughLines(binaria, 1, np.pi/720, 1000)

    # Recopilemos qué ángulos ha encontrado la transformada
    # de hough para cada una de las líneas halladas
    angulos = []
    for linea in lineas:
        rho, theta = linea[0]
        if rho<0:
            theta = -theta

        # Quedarse solo con las rayas próximas a la horizontal
        # (con un error de +-10 grados)
        if not estan_cercanos(theta, np.pi/2, np.deg2rad(10)):
           continue;

        angulos.append(theta)

    # Ahora contemos cuántas veces aparece cada ángulo
    from collections import Counter
    veces = Counter(angulos)

    # Quedémonos con los tres casos más frecuentes
    frecuentes = veces.most_common(3)

    # Y calculemos el promedio de esos tres casos
    suma = sum(angulo*repeticion for angulo,repeticion in frecuentes)
    repeticiones = sum(repeticion for angulo, repeticion in frecuentes)
    angulo = suma/repeticiones

    angulo = np.rad2deg(angulo - np.pi/2)
    print("[INFO] angulo: {:.5f}".format(angulo))

    # Ahora enderecemos la imagen, girando el ángulo detectado
    (h, w) = imagen.shape[:2]
    centro = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(centro, angulo, 1.0)

    girada = cv2.warpAffine(imagen, M, (w, h),
                flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

    # Y volcamos a disco el resultado
    cv2.imwrite(salida, girada)
```

Comment: treeeeeeeeeemendo trabajo Señor, lo felicito, espero que esto solucione el problema del usuario!

Comment: @abulafia  tengo una pregunta  me salio un caso o una excepción

Comment: @NSantos quieres decir, una imagen que no se endereza correctamente? Por favor sube la imagen a imgur y dame un enlace para que la mire yo.

Comment: @abulafia cuando esta derecha la imagen debería encontrar el angulo 0 y no desplazarse, resulta que encuentra un angulo diferente a cero y la desvia

Comment: @abulafia sabes depronto como detectar si esta derecha y no girarla antes de aplicarle la función?

Comment: @NSantos He mejorado la detección de bordes y del ángulo de la hoja, y he corregido un **bug** muy gordo. La nueva versión va bien con todas las imágenes que he probado.

Comment: @abulafia ponte en contacto conmigo porfavor, tengo un amigo en Perú que requiere de vuestra sabiduría para un proyecto (pagado). Gracias :D