# Detectar y recortar automáticamente una foto

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, opencv

Tengo un código que me permite reconocer qué partes de una imagen hay trazos de lápiz.

```
"""
El codigo
Falto:
1.- Enderezar la imagen en caso de estar inclinada.
2.- Agregar margenes superior e inferior para que el encuadre del recorte no sea tan justo.
"""
import sys

sys.path.append('C:/Python36/Lib/site-packages')

import cv2
import numpy as np

imagen = cv2.imread("test.png")
alto, ancho, canales = imagen.shape
contador = 0

# Establece el espacio (desde el el borde izquierdo de la hoja) para considerar como margen 
margen_del_texto = 40

# Evita que identifique bordes de tablas o figuras, como si fueran "marcas"
altura_maxima_de_la_marca = 50

# Puesto que la imagen esta y podria estar inclinada, los extremos de la linea (vertical) podrian estar distantes
anchura_maxima_de_la_marca = 10

# Transforma a escala de grises y luego encuentra los bordes
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)

lineas = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 10, minLineLength=15, maxLineGap=10)

for linea in lineas:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = linea[0]
    # Controla que se busquen las lineas solo dentro del margen, y las medidas especificadas
    if x1 < margen_del_texto and (abs(x2 - x1) < anchura_maxima_de_la_marca) and abs(y2 - y1) < altura_maxima_de_la_marca:
        contador += 1
        cv2.line(imagen, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        # Para ver los recuadros en donde encontro marcas
        cv2.rectangle(imagen, (0, y1), (ancho, y2), (255, 0, 0), 1) 
        recorte = imagen[y1:y2, 1:ancho-1]
        if len(recorte) > 0:
            cv2.imshow("recorte", recorte)
            cv2.imwrite("recorte_"+str(contador)+".png", recorte)
            cv2.destroyWindow("recorte")


cv2.imshow('Marcas detectadas', imagen)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Por ejemplo con esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, construye rectángulos que no necesariamente siguen las líneas. Por eso, **como detectar y recortar automáticamente una foto?**

Al final, el objetivo es extraer el texto de la línea dada

## Intento con el código abulafia

Intenté con el codigo [de Abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141818/como-enderezo-una-imagen-en-python/141895#141895). Es por decir revisar todas las líneas que he encontrado y quedarme con los ángulos que más frecuentemente aparecen. Pero no corresponderá solo a los de las líneas horizontales de la rejilla pero tambien al texto.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

sys.path.append('C:/Python36/Lib/site-packages')

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Leer la imagen
imagen = cv2.imread('test.png')
# Convertirla a gris e invertirla (negativo)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

# Aplicarle un threshold para dejarla binaria
# (los pixels seran 0 o 255)
binaria = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
                cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
print("binaria")
print(binaria)

# Usar la transformada de Hough para encontrar lineas
# en la imagen binarizada, con una resolucion de medio
# grado (pi/720) y quedándose solo con las lineas que
# alcancen puntuacion de 1000 o más (que serán las
# más largas)
lineas = cv2.HoughLines(binaria, 1, np.pi/720, 1000)
print("lineas")
print(lineas)

# Recopilemos que angulos ha encontrado la transformada
# de hough para cada una de las líneas halladas
angulos = []
for linea in lineas:
    theta = linea[0][1]
    angulos.append(theta)

# Ahora contemos cuántas veces aparece cada ángulo
from collections import Counter
veces = Counter(angulos)

# Y quedémonos con el ángulo que más veces se repite
angulo = veces.most_common()[0][0]

# Cambiar el sentido de la rotación si el ángulo es mayor de 180º
if angulo > np.pi/2:
   angulo = -angulo
print("[INFO] angulo: {:.5f}".format(angulo))

# Ahora enderecemos la imagen, girando (en negativo) el ángulo detectado
(h, w) = imagen.shape[:2]
centro = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(centro, -angulo, 1.0)
girada = cv2.warpAffine(imagen, M, (w, h),
            flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

# Y volcamos a disco el resultado
cv2.imwrite("corregida.jpg", girada)
```

`test.png`esta el imagen que pueden ver en la parte superior de la pregunta. Sin embargo me da:

```
(sum_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer>python enderezador.py
binaria
[[  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0   0]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...   0 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0 255 255]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0 255]]
lineas
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "enderezador.py", line 34, in <module>
    for linea in lineas:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Creo que deberías intentar "enderezar" la imagen antes de buscar el trazo de lápiz. Calcular el ángulo que hay que girarla no es demasiado difícil si la página contiene líneas (como la tabla), y aún sin ella, los renglones del texto son una buena pista. Mira [esta respuesta mia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/141895/7123) a un problema similar

Comment: En tu caso veo que ya estás usando la transformada de Hough para detectar el trazo de lápiz. Si asumes que ese trazo es vertical, puedes usar el ángulo encontrado para enderezar la página.

Comment: Como dijo @abulafia puedes girar la imagen hallar los puntos del rectángulo y hacer un recorte de pantalla, yo usé pyautogui) pero seguro hay otros.  https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html

Comment: @abulafia Muchas gracias. Sin embargo despues utilisar la transformada de Hough sobre mi imagen para detecter el trazo de lapiz en el codigo del vinculo obtengo un `None`

Answer (score 1):

El código que has usado tomado de una respuesta mía, tenía un bug, pues no transformaba el ángulo detectado a grados (que es lo que OpenCV esperaba) sino que se lo pasaba en radianes. Había hecho una actualización de la respuesta para corregirlo. Es el segundo código el que vale.

De todas formas, otro enfoque que te proponía en un comentario era usar las propias marcas de lápiz que ya habías detectado en la imagen. Esas marcas, si se supone que van paralelas al margen izquierdo, pueden servirnos para detectar el ángulo que la página está girada, y corregirlo.

Para ello hago varias fases:

1. Lo que ya tenías implementado para convertir la imagen a grises, detectar bordes y aplicar Hough. La lista de rectas encontradas se filtran para quedarse sólo con las que puedan ser marcas de lápiz, mirando que sus dimensiones estén entre ciertos límites como tú hacías (pero esto lo he separado a una función)
2. Con la lista de trazos que han pasado el filtro, se calcula el ángulo de cada uno de ellos, y después el promedio de todos ellos.
3. Se usa ese ángulo para "enderezar" la imagen.
4. Se repite el paso 1 sobre la imagen girada, así como el paso 2 para seleccionar las marcas de lápiz.
5. Se extraen los trozos correspondientes, de la imagen girada.

El código sería este (he metido modificaciones para poder ejecutarlo en un Collaboratory, que es un Notebook Jupyter remoto y no admite `cv2.imshow()`):

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
import cmath
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

##################################################################
# 1. Lo que ya tenías
imagen = cv2.imread("test.png")
alto, ancho, canales = imagen.shape
contador = 0

# Establece el espacio (desde el el borde izquierdo de la hoja) para considerar como margen 
margen = 40

# Evita que identifique bordes de tablas o figuras, como si fueran "marcas"
alto_max = 50

# Puesto que la imagen esta y podria estar inclinada, los extremos de la linea (vertical) podrian estar distantes
ancho_max = 10

# Transforma a escala de grises y luego encuentra los bordes
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)

lineas = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 10, minLineLength=15, maxLineGap=10)

#########################################################################
# 1b. El filtrado de líneas válidas
def linea_valida(linea, margen, ancho_max, alto_max):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = linea
    return x1 < margen and abs(x2 - x1) < ancho_max and abs(y2 - y1) < alto_max

validas = [linea[0] for linea in lineas if linea_valida(linea[0], margen, ancho_max, alto_max)]


##########################################################################
# 2. Detección del ángulo girado
def detecta_giro(lineas):
  angulos = []
  for linea in lineas:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = linea
    vector = complex(x1, y1) - complex(x2, y2)
    angulo = cmath.phase(vector)
    if angulo<0: 
      angulos.append(angulo)
  return np.mean(angulos)

angulo = detecta_giro(validas)

# Convertir a grados
angulo = np.rad2deg(angulo + np.pi/2)

##########################################################################
# 3. Girar la imagen para enderezarla
(h, w) = imagen1.shape[:2]
centro = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(centro, angulo, 1.0)

girada = cv2.warpAffine(imagen1, M, (w, h),
            flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)

##########################################################################
# 4. Repetir la transformada de Hough, ahora sobre la imagen rectificada
gray = cv2.cvtColor(girada, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)
lineas = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 10, minLineLength=15, maxLineGap=10)

# Debido al giro hay menos margen
margen = 35
validas = [linea[0] for linea in lineas if linea_valida(linea[0], margen, ancho_max, alto_max)]

##########################################################################
# 5. Extraer los trozos en la girada
for x1, y1, x2, y2 in validas:
    contador += 1
    cv2.line(girada, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    # Para ver los recuadros en donde encontro marcas
    cv2.rectangle(girada, (0, y1), (ancho, y2), (255, 0, 0), 1) 
    recorte = girada[y1:y2, 1:ancho-1]
    if len(recorte) > 0:
        #cv2.imshow("recorte", recorte)
        cv2.imwrite("recorte_"+str(contador)+".png", recorte)
        #cv2.destroyWindow("recorte")

cv2.imwrite("final.png", girada)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(girada, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((6, 10))
plt.axis('off')
```

El resultado es:

[image: Resultado]

El algoritmo genera 3 ficheros con recortes, a pesar de que el contador de recortes llega hasta 7. Posiblemente haya algún problema a la hora de extraer un recorte si `x1>x2` o algo de este estilo. Pero a partir de aquí ya puedes seguir tú.

Este es un de los recortes extraídos:

[image: recorte]