# Enderezar una foto pequeña con transformada de Hough

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, opencv

Estoy tratando de enderezar una imagen de manera horizontal, para que cuando se la pase a algún OCR, pueda leerla bien ya que si a un OCR se la entrego horizontal, dificulta mucho su lectura.

He estado desarrollando esto en google colab a través de este [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Y9KFr_Ml1Gjy953WHKwxeCYOaVXsJTw8).
Cuando lo intento con esta foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que pasa es que el grado que detecta es muy bajo (`1.8849555`)
Entonces al rotarla, apenas se nota.

Esta es la linea que dibuja.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resulta que tengo este código:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

image1 = cv2.imread('/content/test.jpeg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

#canimg = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200)
#lines= cv2.HoughLines(canimg, 1, np.pi/180.0, 60, np.array([]))
lines= cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 80, np.array([]))
for line in lines:
    rho, theta = line[0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(image1,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
print(theta)
print(rho)

cv2_imshow(image1)
cv2_imshow(edges)

def rotateImage(image, angle):
     image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
     rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
     result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
     return result

cv2_imshow(rotateImage(edges, theta))
```

También vi una respuesta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141818/como-enderezo-una-imagen-en-python/141895#141895) pero no fue satisfactoria.

Al parecer también es importante el tamaño de la imagen que se le entraga, algún consejo? toda ayuda sirve.